# what is proper way to import multiple components from same file in react instead of getting each component imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-redux

I have multiple components or multiple constants in one file, how do i import all that components or constants. Is there any way to import all the components instead of mentioning each component in import statement. please refer below exampe;

```
`
//Constants.js
export const var1="something"
export const var2="something"
export const var3="something"
export const var4="something"
export const var5="something"
export const var6="something"
export const var7="something"
.
.
.


//App.js

import {var1,var2,var3,var4,......} from './Constants'
`
```

instead of this is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other way is using the `*` syntax:

```
import * as Constants from './Constants';
...
// use as so:
const x = 5 * Constants.var1;
```

Read more: http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html